# super-long jquery animation (10 sec) preventing other actions from firing

Tags: jquery, animation, synchronization

Well, this is the exact opposite problem that I normally have with Javascript synchronicity issues.

This time, I have a jQuery animation running for 10 seconds: Actually, quite a few of them. I know it is bloated!

```
function spectrum() { 
    hue = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 128)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256));  
    $('#dubious').animate({boxShadow: "0px 0px 300px rgba(" + hue + ", 0.8) inset"}, 10000);
    $('.strip').animate({borderColor: "rgba(" + hue + ", 0.25)"}, 10000);
    $('.element').animate({boxShadow: "0px 0px 400px rgba(" + hue + ", 0.45)"}, 10000);
    $('#outer_container').animate({borderColor: "0px 0px 400px rgba(" + hue + ", 0.45)"}, 10000);
    $('#dubious_box').animate({boxShadow: "0px 0px 40px rgba(" + hue + ", 1)"}, 10000, function() {spectrum();});
}
```

.. basically, it picks a random color, and then each of these elements transitions to that hue over 10 seconds.

Again, probably too bloated to be terribly practical, but its just [SO COOL LOOKING](http://www.dubiousgallery.com)..

Anyway, the real problem child is [here](http://www.dubiousgallery.com/gallery.php).

You'll notice, if you click one of the images **in the top row** (don't try clicking the rest, that's another issue i'm hammering out), and **wait for about ten seconds**, you'll get a popup with a blown-up version of the picture. Then **click the picture again, and wait ten more seconds**, and it'll finally blink out like a TV.

Anyway, the click event:

```
$(".gallery_image").click(function() {
        $("#blowup").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        $("#outer_container").animate({opacity: "1", height: "500"});
    });
```

When I turn off the `spectrum()` loop, the problem goes away.

**Thanks for taking a look** :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works well, combining insight and code from both @nnnnnn and @Praveen.

The code is for a gallery that has a **looping color-changing animation in the background** (When a user clicks a thumbnail, the animation in the background has to stop, the click action takes place, and the background animation kicks in again. The same happens when a user clicks the image or presses Esc to close the image.

The following code is where all **looping background animation** animations running on the page (**4**) stop, then ends one more animation (`outer_container`) before adding a new animation to its queue.

After all that, I must ask:

***Is it possible to end all animation on all items with a single line of jQuery? would this be more or less efficient than stopping them all independently?***

```
$(".gallery_image").click(function() {
        $('#dubious').stop(true); //end all active animations --v
        $('.strip').stop(true);
        $('.element').stop(true);
        $('#dubious_box').stop(true); // --^
        $("#blowup").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        $("#outer_container").stop(true).animate({opacity: "1", height: "500"},
        function() { //callback
            spectrum();
        });
    });

    $('#blowup').click(function() {
        $('#dubious').stop(true); //end all active animations --v
        $('.strip').stop(true);
        $('.element').stop(true);
        $('#dubious_box').stop(true); // --^
        $("#outer_container").stop(true).animate({opacity: "0", height: "0"})
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stopping the current animation on the element in question:

```
$(".gallery_image").click(function() {
     $("#blowup").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
     $("#outer_container").stop(true).animate({opacity: "1", height: "500"});
     // -------------------^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

See the [`.stop()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to decide what parameters to pass in - I'm not sure whether `.stop(true)` or `.stop(true,true)` is better for your situation.

If you don't call `.stop()` then calling `.animate()` just adds to the end of the existing animation queue for that element.

Comment: Thank you for explaining .stop() to me. `.stop(true)` ended up working very well. I posted the working code above.

Answer (score 1):

Remove spectrum(); from onload and use only when needed.

```
$(".gallery_image").click(function() {
        $("#blowup").attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
        $("#outer_container").stop().animate({opacity: "1", height: "500"},
        function(){//Callback finish loading outer_container
            spectrum();
        });
});

$('#blowup').click(function() {
        $("#outer_container").stop().animate({opacity: "0", height: "0"}); 
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Actually, I do want `spectrum()` to run continually. I used  your idea but did not remove `spectrum()` from onload and put it in a callback from both `.click` functions for `.gallery_image` and `#blowup`.